# Javascript If-statement problem understanding

Tags: javascript

So I have this javascript that reads a textfile's last row and displays it on a highchart. If I dont include this statement is only writes the same row over and over. I have a RPI that stimulates a traffic jam. So when it becomes red it adds a row in the textfile as follows:
2019-12-13;10:52:08;5;143.
The 5 is number of cars and 143 is the nitrogen oxide.
Can some please explain the second if-statement?

```
        var helpVar="";
        if (typeof (EventSource) !== "undefined") {
            var source = new EventSource("./lastRow.php");
            source.onmessage = function (event) {

                var obj = event.data.split(";");

                if(helpVar==="" || helpVar !==obj[1]){
                    helpVar = obj[1];
                    var datumtid = obj[0] + "<br>" + obj[1];
                    $timestamp.push(datumtid);
                    myChart.series[0].addPoint(parseInt(obj[2]));
                }
            };
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
        }
```

Comment: There is actually 2 `if`s. Which one you don't understand ?

Comment: I've edited the document. I mean the second if-statement. Also i have created a variable called helpVar.